# React update intl dont work: Uncaught ReferenceError: Could not find Intl message:

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I did upgrade from react 0.13 to the newest one. Here a list of the dependencies I changed.

```
react: 0.13.3 -> 0.14.3  
react-dom: none  -> 0.14.3  
react-router: 0.13.3 -> 1.0.3  
react-history: none -> 1.0.3  
react-intl: 1.2.0 -> 1.2.2  
intl: 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
```

But I cant get the translations work again.

***Uncaught ReferenceError: Could not find Intl message: test***

```
// app.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var routes = require('./routes');
var createHistory = require('history').createHistory;

var intlData = {
    locales: 'en',
    messages: {
        test: 'Test'
    }
};

ReactDom.render(<Router history={createHistory()} intl={intlData}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));


// Test.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactIntl = require('react-intl');
var IntlMixin = ReactIntl.IntlMixin;

var Test = React.createClass({

    mixins: [IntlMixin],

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>
                    {this.getIntlMessage('test')}
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Test;
```

What did I miss in the update? What is the correct way to init my messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntlMixin` works by [looking on the context](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/v1.0.1/src/mixin.js#L44-L53) for the relevant data, specifically, [`this.context.locales`, `this.context.formats`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/v1.0.1/src/mixin.js#L79-L80), and [`this.context.messages`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/v1.0.1/src/mixin.js#L97). It was probably the React Router upgrade from 0.x to 1.x — which changed the way the top-level component is handled — that broke things.

However, if you look at the source linked above, you can see that the mixin looks for the data on `this.context` *only if* it's not found on `this.props`. Thus, if you could pass your internationalization data to every route handler as a prop, things would work fine. Luckily, React Router allows you to do just that [via `createElement`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props).

`createElement` should be a function that takes two arguments: the component React Router wants to render, and the props it wants to send it. The function should render that component with the given props. The default implementation looks like this:

```js
function createElement(Component, props) {
  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

However, you can further customize how the component gets rendered. For your case, it might look something like:

```js
function createIntlElement(Component, props) {
  return <Component intl={intlData} {...props} />
}
```

although it looks like from the React Intl docs that the props should be split out, so if that doesn't work, maybe more like:

```js
function createIntlElement(Component, props) {
  return <Component {...props}
                    locales={intlData.locales}
                    messages={intlData.messages} />
}
```

or, more simply using the spread syntax,

```js
function createIntlElement(Component, props) {
  return <Component {...props} {...intlData} />
}
```

You then instruct the router to use your `createElement` function by passing it to the `createElement` prop:

```js
var router = (
  <Router history={createHistory()} createElement={createIntlElement}>
    {routes}
  </Router>
);
ReactDom.render(router, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Don't forget to include `IntlMixin` on all your route handlers so that child components that *aren't* directly rendered by the router still have access to the context.

---

React Intl version 2 (now in beta) appears to use a `IntlProvider` component, much like Redux's `Provider` component, to provide the correct context for you, so using `createElement` should not be necessary when using that version.

Comment: tried now to update to v2 with adding IntlProvider around the return of my Root component and changed the intlmessage to object syntax but now get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `App`.`

Comment: @AlexanderSchranz Remember that v2 is still in beta; there may still be bugs in the implementation. Also there is a fairly extensive [upgrade guide](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) you will need to go through to upgrade to v2. Either way, there's not enough information here to debug that particular problem.

Comment: Here is the complete code I used currently https://github.com/alexander-schranz/react-setup

Comment: Ok could get around the problem by replace my translates with <FormattedMessage> Component. I think there is something missing in the upgrade guide for the getIntlMessage the syntax change to an object seems for me not the right thing. Thankyou for your help!